AddPropertyComment doesn't produce comment
When using the following recipe, it produces nothing. I can't see any errors either.
  - org.openrewrite.properties.AddPropertyComment:
      propertyKey: spring.datasource.oracleucp.max-pool-size
      comment: "https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/jjucp/controlling-pool-size.html."
      commentOutProperty: true

My pom.xml looks like this, maybe it is a missing dependency that I can't figure out?
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.46.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <exportDatatables>true</exportDatatables>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>com.oracle.spring.hikaritoucp</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.41.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.24.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

